# Blur or low Resolution icon in Lower density device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, screen-density

I have XML files of the icon inside drawable.device's which has density 380 or more has a perfect resolution but Device which has lower Density like 320 Images are getting blur.

I Tried to make lower density drawable folders to solve the Problem but, after putting icon inside that folder, it's giving me an error of duplication.

What should I do for get perfect resolution for all device?

Comment: did you tried vector drawables??

Comment: I m using vector resource .(svg to xml)

Comment: can you add a sample drawable?

Comment: Like I mention in Question my I did and result was duplication of files error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found following simple answer : Just Increase the size of icon in xml. In my case original size was 24 dp and I modify it to 98 and that's it.

Sample:

```
<vector android:height="98dp" android:viewportHeight="99.261"
    android:viewportWidth="99.261" android:width="98dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M17.464,65.202l-...."/>
</vector>
```